# cannot read spec file ‘libgomp.spec’

Tags: linux, gcc, openmp

trying to compile a C++ application with OpenMP offloading on Ubuntu 23.10 with GCC 13, and I get the error message

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-13: fatal error: cannot read spec file ‘libgomp.spec’: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
nvptx mkoffload: fatal error: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-13 returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
```

But I can see that the file in question does exist, namely in

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libgomp.spec
```

what command line arguments do I need to give GCC in order to actually find it?

Comment: Seeing the `nvptx mkoffload`: For GCC 10 there is a [`gcc-10-offload-nvptx`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/gcc-10-offload-nvptx) package containing a `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/accel/nvptx-none/libgomp.spec`. Same for 11 and 12. The corresponding GCC 13 package [does **not** contain a `libgomp.spec` file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/amd64/gcc-13-offload-nvptx/filelist). Maybe the one you found is just for CPU multi-threading and not for offloading.

Comment: There is already a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-13/+bug/2036593) about this since September. But no reaction from the package maintainers.

Comment: I see. indeed I got it working with gcc-12 now. Good enough for the moment. Thank you guys.